# Can Python subclasses return class of type(self) from method inherited from a parent class?

Tags: python, oop

Suppose I have a parent class `Parent` and two child classes `Child1` and `Child2`. Suppose `Parent` contains a method usable by both subclasses. Is it possible for this method to return a new instance of the same class of whatever class calls it, even if the particular subclass calling it is not known when the method is defined in the parent class?

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        pass
    def my_method(self):
        return self.__class__(foo)

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__(foo)

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__(foo)

parent = Parent('hello')
type(p.my_method())
>>> class<Parent>

child1 = Child1('hey')
type(child1.my_method())
>>> class<Child1>

child2 = Child2('yo')
type(child2.my_method())
>>> class<Child2>
```

**EDIT**
I had made a mistake in passing foo without initializing it as an attribute first. The following code achieves the behavior I'm going for, but I'd be interested to know if this could lead to design problems down the road, so feedback on that would be appreciated.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
    def my_method(self):
        return self.__class__(self.foo)

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__(foo)

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__(foo)


p = Parent(foo='hi')
print(type(p.my_method()))
>>>__main__.Parent

c1 = Child1(foo='hey')
print(type(c1.my_method()))
>>>__main__.Child1

c2 = Child2(foo='hey')
print(type(c2.my_method()))
>>>__main__.Child2
```

Comment: Did you try it and see? Note, you don't actually have inheritance in the code you provided

Comment: Can you elaborate what are you expecting ?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I updated to include inheritance. I'm expecting to see a method of the same type as the child class be returned, even though the existence of the child class isn't known at the point at which the method is defined in the parent class

Answer (score 0):

What you have won't work, because you have `my_method` being an instance method, but you're trying to call it without an instance.

If you make that a class method, it can work, although I personally think this is a bad design choice:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        pass
    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls):
        return cls(0)

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__(foo)

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__(foo)

print(type(Parent.my_method()))
print(type(Child1.my_method()))
print(type(Child2.my_method()))
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.Parent'>
<class '__main__.Child1'>
<class '__main__.Child2'>
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to make sure the objects were instantiated first. Would something like that work?

Comment: Also would you mind elaborating on why making it a class method would be a bad design choice? Thank you

Comment: The question becomes, what's the point?  You can do it with a class method, but why?  Why is `Child1.my_method()` better than `Child(0)`, which does the same thing in a cleaner way?  What are you gaining?

Comment: Ok I noticed I had not created a `self.foo` in `__init__()` first. After doing that I was able to achieve what I'm going for. Thank you for the input.